# Using ArcGIS field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

This field calculate returns an error, whats wrong with it?

```py
def Reclass(A):
  elif ( A>= 0.208113 and A <= 0.261517):
   return "Low"
  elif (A > 0.261517 and A < 0.301951):
   return "Moderate"
  elif (A > 0.301951 and A < 0.335518):
   return "Moderate"
  elif (A > 0.335518 and A < 0.36756):
   return "Moderate"
  elif (A > 0.36756):
   return "High"

Reclass(!grid_code!)
```

[image: HERE IS MY SITUATION]

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to include the text of whatever error you are seeing, please?  Also, please be aware that potential answerers usually prefer to choose which questions to answer first by question quality rather than statements of urgency: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3672/should-statements-of-urgency-be-removed-from-questions  I have edited your question to try and prevent it from attracting further downvotes.  I recommend reviewing [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question)

Answer (score 4):

```py
def Reclass(A):
  Low = 0.208113
  Moderate = 0.261517
  High = 0.36756
  if Low <= A <= Moderate:
    val = "Low"
  elif Moderate < A <= High:
    val = "Moderate"
  elif A > High:
    val = "High"
  return val
```

```
Reclass(!grid_code!)
```

This will do what your code seems to be trying to do. My concern is that I think you need to think more carefully about what it is that you are doing. Those numbers appear very arbitrary, and your original code wouldn't have been able to deal with a value of `0.36756` (which I assigned to `"Moderate"`, whatever that means). What happens to values less than `0.208113`?

Comment: +1 Nice clean solution.  You could go one step further and remove the `and` statements (e.g. `if Low <= A <= Moderate:`)

Comment: tnx alpha..ill try this...but what should i put the lower part of the second box

Comment: `Reclass(!grid_code!)` is perfect.

Comment: You need to make sure that you have no syntax errors in the code block. ArcMap does not make this easy for you by insisting on two spaces for each indent and not using a monospace font. Ensure that your code is properly indented as above.

Comment: 0.208 is the lowest value ....alpha

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to be sure without seeing your error message but I suspect this will work:

```py
def Reclass(A):
  if ( A>= 0.208113 and A <= 0.261517):
    return "Low"
  elif (A > 0.261517 and A < 0.301951):
    return "Moderate"
  elif (A > 0.301951 and A < 0.335518):
    return "Moderate"
  elif (A > 0.335518 and A < 0.36756):
    return "Moderate"
  elif (A > 0.36756):
    return "High"

Reclass(!grid_code!)
```

You need an `if` statement before you can use optional `elif` statements (and optionally an `else` statement too).

Comment: Error again 000989 ..."Parsing error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level (line 3) ..